# How to add labels to all Grafana Mimir alerts

Tags: label, prometheus, config, global, prometheus-alertmanager

I have setup a Grafana, Mimir, Loki, Tempo and Grafana Agent stack running in Kubernetes, deployed by Helm. I have imported all the mixin-compiled alerts and now have about ~300 alerts imported.

I would like to be able to add labels to all these alerts.
i.e `env=prod`

In Prometheus you can update the prometheus config to include

```
  prometheus.yml:
    global:
      external_labels:
        environment: prod
```

Can the same be done in Mimir?

I cant seem to find any way of adding a `prometheus.yaml` or the required global configuration to Mimir. Is this even possible?
Or is there another way to add external labels to everything in Mimir?

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the labels in grafana-agent config, like:

```
prometheus.remote_write "metamonitoring" {
  external_labels = {
    environment = "prod",
  }
  endpoint {
    url = env("MIMIR_URL")
    basic_auth {
      username = nonsensitive(remote.kubernetes.secret.credentials.data["REMOTE_WRITE_USERNAME"])
      password = remote.kubernetes.secret.credentials.data["REMOTE_WRITE_PASSWORD"]
    }
    headers = {
      "X-Scope-OrgID" = "metamonitoring",
    }
  }
}
```